# Декодирование звука при помощи FFMpeg вывод при помощи OpenAL

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg, аудио

Пытаюсь Воспроизвести звук при помощи связки OpenAL+FFmpeg Вывода звука вроде добился, но звук идет с прерываниями, треском, и кажется не много быстрее чем нужно, исходник прилагается
 [Библиотеки](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19UI2tjbkIGqVUpWiCfNI3F8vjNhlANj0)

```
function TOggStream.Playback: Boolean;
begin
  if Playing then
  begin
    Result := True;
    exit;
  end;
  if not Stream(Buffers[0]) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    exit;
  end;
  if not Stream(Buffers[1]) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    exit;
  end;
  alSourceQueueBuffers(Source, 2, @Buffers);
  alSourcePlay(Source);
  Result := True;
end;



function TOggStream.Update: Boolean;
var
  Processed: Integer;
  Active: Boolean;
  Buffer: TALUInt;
begin
  Active := False;
  alGetSourcei(Source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, @Processed);
  if Processed > 0 then
    repeat
      alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, @Buffer);
      Active := Stream(Buffer);
      alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, @Buffer);
      dec(Processed);
    until Processed <= 0;
  Result := Active;
end;

function TOggStream.Stream(Buffer: TALUInt): Boolean;
var
  Data: PChar;
  Size: Integer;
  Section: Integer;
  Res: Integer;
  ff: integer;
  BufferTMP: array[1..BufferSize + SIZEOF(Integer)] of Integer;
begin
  Size := 0;
    zeroMemory(@BufferTMP, SizeOf(BufferTMP));
  GetMem(Data, BufferSize + SizeOf(Size));
  while (Size < BufferSize) do
  begin
  av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, @MyPacket);
    begin
      if (MyPacket.stream_index = audio_index) then
      begin
      avcodec_decode_audio4(dec_ctxAud, AudFrame, ff, @MyPacket);

      Res := av_samples_get_buffer_size(@AudFrame.linesize[0], dec_ctxAud.channels, Audframe.nb_samples, dec_ctxAud.sample_fmt, 1);
     for icnt:=0 to 1 do
     OldAuddata_size:= MyCircBuf.Write(AudFrame.Data[icnt],res);

      MyCircBuf.Read(BufferTMP,res);
     Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;

      av_free_packet(@MyPacket);
       end;

    if Res > 0 then
    begin
      inc(Size, Res);
    end
    else if Res < 0 then
      Log.Add(ErrorString(Res))
    else
      break;
  end;
  if Size = 0 then
  begin
    Result := False;
    exit;
  end;

  alBufferData(Buffer, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, @BufferTMP, Size, dec_ctxAud.sample_rate);

  Result := True;
  FreeMem(Data);
end;
```

Кто сталкивался, помогите пожалуйста разобраться в проблемме

Comment: `if dec_ctxAud.channels = 1 then
audFormat := AL_FORMAT_MONO16
else
audFormat := AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;`
Почему именно 16? Звук не обязательно должен быть 16-ти битным. И еще в вопросе слишком много кода, оставьте только то, что относится к воспроизведению и настройкам вывода звука.

Comment: Stereo16 потому что ffmpeg при запросе формата семплов возвращает s16p

Comment: ffmpeg это хорошо, а в файле, из которого вы достаете звуковой поток в буфер, он в каком формате? Не могли бы вы убрать из кода не относящиеся к делу комментарии и дописать свои пояснения что происходит. Для чего нужен `MyCircBuf` если вы пишете в него раскодированный фрейм, а потом пытаетесь из него что-то прочитать и больше он нигде не используется?

Comment: MyCircBuf это класс TCircleBuffer созданный на основе TMemoryStream Я пробывал как с ним так и без него, если я Вас правильно понял, то сам файл сжат в MP3 44100, 112кб/с стерео так же пробывал другие файлы, кстати в выражении S16P меня смущает P на конце, как я вычитал это означает planar.

Comment: Не много изменил процедуру записи в буффер теперь она выглядит так:          for icnt:=0 to 1 do
         OldAuddata_size:= MyCircBuf.Write(AudFrame.Data[icnt],res)         теперь четко слышно что за песня играет, но звук воспроизводится быстрее чем нужно и остался треск

Comment: Меня очень смущает этот ваш странный буфер и то, как вы передаете поток в `alBufferData`. Вы уверены, что оба канала (если `AudFrame.Data[icnt]` это каналы звука) нужно передавать последовательно друг за другом? Попробуйте заменить цикл `for icnt:=0 to 1` на `CopyMemory(@BufferTMP[0], @AudFrame.Data[0][0], res);` и `CopyMemory(@BufferTMP[res], @AudFrame.Data[1][0], res);`. `res` - это размер буфера на все каналы или только на один? Если на один, то зачем тогда передавать в функцию получения размера буфера количество каналов?

Comment: Res мне кажется это общий размер буфера во фрейме, CopyMemory(@BufferTMP[0], @AudFrame.Data[0][0], res); выдает Constant expression violates subrange bounds на @BufferTMP[0], а CopyMemory(@BufferTMP[res], @AudFrame.Data[1][0], res); ругается  Array type required на @AudFrame.Data[1][0], Если честно я впервые вижу что так передаются массивы :AudFrame.Data[1][0] компилирую на Delphi7

Comment: а насчет данных в data[0] и data[1] я вычитал (кажется на gamedev) что там именно каналы

Comment: Последние эксперементы показали что в скорости воспроизведения был виноват формат сэмплов решил проблему так: `Res:=av_samples_get_buffer_size(@AudFrame.linesize[0], dec_ctxAud.channels,Audframe.nb_samples, dec_ctxAud.sample_fmt,1);      
Mres:= av_samples_alloc(MmyData, @AudFrame.linesize[0], dec_ctxAud.channels, 32767, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);
 
FrameFinished := swr_convert(swr,MmyData, AudFrame.nb_samples, AudFrame.Data[0], AudFrame.nb_samples);     
CopyMemory(@BufferTMP, MmyData, Mres);` но что делать с провалами и щелчками пока не понятно, и да @kot-da-vinci вы были правы

Comment: Данные находятся только в data[0], проверил на спец файле с поочерёдно записанными данными(сначала левый канал, потом правый и вместе)

Comment: У меня появилось предположение, что изза того что выходной буффер(BufferTMP) в конце забит 0 происходит эффект прерывания, но я не уверен

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался, вся проблема была в размере буффера, вынес процедуру декодирования в отдельный поток, убавил размер буффера и увеличил их количество с 2 до 10. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Рад, что удалось помочь. Опубликуйте пожалуйста решение целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Процедура заполнения буффера :

```
if av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, @MyPacket)>=0 then
begin
 if(MyPacket.stream_index=audio_index) then
  begin

   decoded:=avcodec_decode_audio4(dec_ctxAud, AudFrame, ff, @MyPacket);
               if ff>0 then
    begin
  Res:=av_samples_get_buffer_size(@AudFrame.linesize[0], AudFrame.channels,Audframe.nb_samples, dec_ctxAud.sample_fmt,1);;
  av_samples_alloc(MmyData, nil, AudFrame.channels, AudFrame.nb_samples, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);
FrameFinished := swr_convert(swr,MmyData,  AudFrame.nb_samples,PByte(AudFrame.data[0]) , AudFrame.nb_samples);
Mres:=av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16)*AudFrame.channels*FrameFinished;
 CopyMemory(@BufferTMP, MmyData, res );
        end;
   if res > 0 then
begin
inc(Size,res);
alBufferData(Buffer, audFormat, @BufferTMP, res,dec_ctxAud.sample_rate );
Result := True;
 end;
    if res = 0 then
begin
Result := True;
end;
end;
```

инициализация OAL

```
     alGenBuffers(10, @Buffers);
    alGenSources(1, @Source);
   alSource3f(source, AL_POSITION, 0, 0, 0);
   alSource3f(source, AL_VELOCITY, 0, 0, 0);
   alSource3f(source, AL_DIRECTION, 0, 0, 0);
   alSourcef(source, AL_ROLLOFF_FACTOR, 0);
   alSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
```

И размер буффера

```
    BufferSize = 6162
```

Comment: Только на днях у меня опять возникла проблема, если формат семплов до ресемплера S16P то ресемплер легко превращает его в S16, но если формат семплов FLTP то опять начинаются звуковые артефакты. на каком-то из форумов вычитал что нужно использовать вместо 'swr_convert(swr,MmyData,  AudFrame.nb_samples,AudFrame.data[0] , AudFrame.nb_samples);'   'swr_convert(swr,MmyData,  AudFrame.nb_samples,PByte(AudFrame.extended_data) , AudFrame.nb_samples);', но при использовании  extended_data функция swr_convert вылетает с AccessViolation at adress 00000000 Read of address 0000000

Comment: Хотя в самих исходниках FFMpeg на Си  они делают так `swr_convert(swrCtx_, &outbuf, frame_->nb_samples, (const uint8_t **)frame_->extended_data, frame_->nb_samples);` не пойму в чем проблема я так же как и в этом коде привожу указатель к Pbyte